# Iphone 4 without itunes or lock button

Tags: itunes, unlock

Okay my iphone needs to connect to itunes, but my device doesnt support itunes and my iphone lock button is broke, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

## Option #1

1. Take it to the Apple store and have them fix the lock button.
2. Take your iPhone back home, and run iTunes on a friend's computer.

## Option #2

1. Take it to the Apple store and have them do everything for you.

## Option #3

1. Go to the Apple store and get your lock button fixed.
2. Get a real computer that supports iTunes in some way or another and use that.

## Option #4

1. Go to the Apple store and get a real iPhone - one that actually supports modern software.

In reality, you've got no good options.  You need to go to the Apple store one way or another.  Sorry bro, welcome to 2016.